# Why in the global server variable, the query_param cell is not valid

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, laradock

I am trying to set up email verification, but because of wrong configuration of either, server or php I always get 403 Invalid signature error. If you know how to solve this problem I would be very grateful. All the solutions I googled don't work for me.

my route with params:

```
https://mysite.lo/email/verify/1001/82f42f0bbc6880958a68b56159cb7cbf96199ddf?expires=1642686658&signature=87fa7d09653adcbbeb4dd99bec9a97395d7417bdfeffc145a1c5d6e80feeb726
```

PHP DEBUG

```
$request->server->get('QUERY_STRING')
```

output:

```
/email/verify/1001/82f42f0bbc6880958a68b56159cb7cbf96199ddf&expires=1642686658&signature=87fa7d09653adcbbeb4dd99bec9a97395d7417bdfeffc145a1c5d6e80feeb726
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mqN38.png)

But there should be another output, starting from ? to the end, for example:

```
expires=1642686658&signature=87fa7d09653adcbbeb4dd99bec9a97395d7417bdfeffc145a1c5d6e80feeb726
```

Or am I misunderstanding something?

Anyway, I don't understand why this is happening.
The nginx settings are below.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name mysite.lo *.mysite.lo;

    ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/ssl/ssl.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/ssl.key;

    access_log /var/www/mysite/mpa/storage/logs/nginx_access.log;
    error_log /var/www/mysite/mpa/storage/logs/nginx_error.log;

    root /var/www/mysite/mpa/public;
    index index.php;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    charset utf-8;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    # serve static files directly
    location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html)$ {
        access_log off;
        expires max;
        log_not_found off;
    }

    # removes trailing slashes (prevents SEO duplicate content issues)
    if (!-d $request_filename)
    {
        rewrite ^/(.+)/$ /$1 permanent;
    }

    # enforce NO www
    if ($host ~* ^www\.(.*))
    {
        set $host_without_www $1;
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ $scheme://$host_without_www/$1 permanent;
    }

    # unless the request is for a valid file (image, js, css, etc.), send to bootstrap
    if (!-e $request_filename)
    {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 last;
        break;
    }

    location / {
         try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri /index.php =404;
        fastcgi_pass php-upstream;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        #fixes timeouts
        fastcgi_read_timeout 600;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

This is the local environment.
I am using: laradock php 8

Comment: Does `$request->server->get('REQUEST_URI')` show the same string? Check your `fastcgi_param` file, it should contain a line similar to `fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING $query_string;`

Comment: @IvanShatsky fastcgi_param file: 
fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

Comment: `$request->server->get('QUERY_STRING')`: 
/email/verify/1001/82f42f0bbc6880958a68b56159cb7cbf96199ddf&expires=1642696348&signature=e7e79cadf757d84bab5c4e95e916cfe0c4fa18c10be8df883c20642025fb2e39

`$request->server->get('REQUEST_URI')` :
/email/verify/1001/82f42f0bbc6880958a68b56159cb7cbf96199ddf?expires=1642696348&signature=e7e79cadf757d84bab5c4e95e916cfe0c4fa18c10be8df883c20642025fb2e39

Comment: @IvanShatsky The strange thing is that in **Query_String** there is no `?` but instead there is `&`

Comment: Got it. Is is your `rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 last;` do it adding an original request URI as the first query string argument.

Comment: For example, you can change it to `rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?route=/$1 last;` and your query string will become `route=/email/verify/1001/82f42f0bbc6880958a68b56159cb7cbf96199ddf&expires=1642696348&signature=e7e79cadf757d84bab5c4e95e916cfe0c4fa18c10be8df883c20642025fb2e39`.

Comment: From  the [documentation](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite): _If a replacement string includes the new request arguments, the previous request arguments are appended after them._

Comment: @IvanShatsky Thank you, kind man, now I understand what the problem is, you have helped me a lot. I was getting very frustrated with this ignorance =). Now I need to figure it out so that the query string becomes this: `expires=1642696348&signature=e7e79cadf757d84bab5c4e95e916cfe0c4fa18c10be8df883c20642025fb2e39`

Comment: @IvanShatsky Make it an answer, and I'll mark it as a solution =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is your `rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 last;` rule adds an original URI as the first query argument. As `rewrite` directive documentation [says](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite):

> If a `replacement` string includes the new request arguments, the previous request arguments are appended after them.

You can avoid adding an original URI as the first query argument specifically for the `/email/verify/` route:

```
    if (!-e $request_filename)
    {
        # do not append an original URI to this route
        rewrite ^/email/verify/ /index.php last;
        # but append it to everything else
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 last;
        break;
    }
```